# Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Set<Exercise>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection' - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, foreach, set

I am getting the error: "Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Set' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'" when trying to display items I have selected from a list in another view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExSetView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var selectedItems = Set<Exercise>()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Set Count: \(selectedItems.count)")
                ForEach(selectedItems) { e in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: ExSetInputView(exset: e),
                        label: {
                            Text(e.exercisename)
                        }
                    )}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is on the line `ForEach(selectedItems) { e in`

I have no clue how to fix this. Ultimately I just want to display the selected items by their property of exercisename as a navigation link. Is there another way without using For Each? Is the issue because it is a set and not an array? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: you can simply use `ForEach(Array(selectedItems)) {...}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ForEach` requires an ordered data source, a `Set` is unordered by definition.

A simple solution is to sort the Set for example by `exercisename`

```
ForEach(selectedItems.sorted{$0.exercisename < $1.exercisename})
```

The result of `sorted` is an array which is `'RandomAccessCollection` compliant.